# Increase the probability of death with age using Pyhton

Tags: python, class, oop, random, probability

Using OOP I want to generate a definition in a class which increase the probability of death every year after the 45 years old and no one can live more than 90 years.

It means that after your birthday 45 the probability of death will increase every year and the oldes age to die is 90.

I tried some functions importing "random", but it creates probabilities randomly every year after the 45 and not in an increasing probability way.

The main idea is that as older you are the probability to die should increse after the 45 years and must be 100% at the age of 90.

Comment: Have fun writing it!

Comment: Marcel, the right way to go about this is to define what's called a hazard function, which is the probably of dying in the next short time, given that you've survived until a given age. Then you can derive the survival function from that (probability that you live past a given age), and then the cumulative distribution function is just 1 - survival. Finally, you can generate random numbers between 0 and 1 and solve, perhaps numerically, cdf(age) = (random number) to get a random age. The Wikipedia page for survival analysis has the basic definitions.

Comment: @Friedrich That's not a constructive comment.

Comment: @RobertDodier that is correct and it is so on purpose. My comment mirrors the fact that the question isn't one either. There's no question mark, not even an imperative. There are two hints to fathom the OP's intentions, the term "I want" in the first sentence and "I tried" (without code) in the third one. Well, if you want something you gotta do something for it, right? But I get your hint. I will write boring comments like "share your code", "SO is not a code writing service" etc. in the future.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I really appreciate it. I will look into the "survival analysis" to understand more about this and implement it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would do:

```py
import random

sudden_death_probability = []
max_value = 0

for i in range(0, 46):
    max_value += random.random()
    sudden_death_probability.append(max_value)

sudden_death_probability = [p / max_value for p in sudden_death_probability]
print(sudden_death_probability)


def get_sudden_death_probability(age: int) -> float:
    if age < 45:
        return 0
    if age > 90:
        return 1
    return sudden_death_probability[age - 45]
```

**Edit:**

More "elegant" way:

```py
sudden_death_probability = [random.random() for _ in range(0,45)]
sudden_death_probability.sort()
print(sudden_death_probability)


def get_sudden_death_probability(age: int) -> float:
    if age < 45:
        return 0
    if age >= 90:
        return 1
    return sudden_death_probability[age - 45]
```